# How to bind a list of Tab.Items of type<ShellContent> dynamically AND within XAML with xamarin.forms-shell

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

How to add items of type ShellContent dynamically with data binding considering the MVVM pattern. I want to bind a last of TabViewModels to the Tab.Items collection. NOT codebehind which I can not test.

Instead of the 6 ShellContent objects I want to bind any number during runtime.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<FlyoutItem Route="animals"
                Title="Animals"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
        <Tab Title="Domestic"
             Route="domestic"
             Icon="paw.png">

            <Tab.Items>

                <ShellContent Route="cats"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="sisi"
                          Icon="cat.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
                <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="dog.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
                <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="dog.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
                <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="dog.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
                <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="dog.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
                <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="dog.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
            </Tab.Items>


        </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add property `x:Name="myTab"` for your `Tab` and use function `void Add(T item);` to add child item into your `Tab`.For example:

```
   <FlyoutItem Route="animals" x:Name="mFlyoutItem"
                Title="Animals"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <Tab Title="Domes.123"
             Route="domestic"
             x:Name="myTab"
             Icon="paw.png">
            <Tab.Items>
            <ShellContent Route="cats"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Cats"
                          Icon="cat.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
            <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                          Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                          Title="Dogs"
                          Icon="dog.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
            </Tab.Items>
        </Tab>
   </FlyoutItem>
```

Then add `ShellContent` in your code behind like this:

```
 myTab.Items.Add(new DogsPage());
```

If you want to change the property of `ShellContent`(e.g. the `Title`), you can use following code:

```
ShellContent shellContent = new ShellContent();
shellContent.Content = new DogsPage();
shellContent.Title = "testTitle";

myTab.Items.Add(shellContent);
```

**Update**

For `ShellContent.BindingContext` , you can refer to this issue:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6444

This bug has already been fixed,so we need to update `Xamarin Form` to the latest version.

The sample code is:

```
  <TabBar>
    <Tab >
        <ShellContent >
            <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:Page1 BindingContext="{Binding Page1VM}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
        </ShellContent>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Comment: Seems I should have been more clear. Thus I rephrased my title/question.

Comment: @Pascal   I have updated the answer ,you can check it.

Comment: I assume  that Page1VM is not an Items collection holding the tabviewmodels, right? Because then its useless for me.